# Is it possible to migrate and upgrade an Artifactory (2.2.5 to 3.7.0) from a Derby-backed database to a MySQL one?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to upgrade an old Artifactory installation from `2.2.5` to `3.7.0`. I have a full zip backup. Importing into an Artifactory on a separate machine with a pristine `3.7.0` installation (using the built-in) Derby did pass successfully. I am now wondering how to approach the problem of migrating to a MySQL database. I understand that these are completely different databases, but I was hoping the importer would be able to figure out what to do.

Is this possible at all and is there some documentation you could point me to on how to do this exactly?

Do I need to do an incremental upgrade instead (to `2.6.6` first) despite the fact that an import against a `3.7.0` Artifatory with Derby is working?

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while extracting /path/to/backup/thebackup.zip
    at org.artifactory.util.ZipUtils.extractFiles(ZipUtils.java:163) ~[artifactory-common-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.util.ZipUtils.extract(ZipUtils.java:93) ~[artifactory-common-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.wicket.page.importexport.system.ImportSystemPanel$3.onSubmit(ImportSystemPanel.java:181) ~[artifactory-web-application-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.common.wicket.component.links.TitledAjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(TitledAjaxSubmitLink.java:59) [artifactory-web-common-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$1.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:172) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1151) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:834) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:762) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:158) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:184) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:369) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor160.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:255) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:781) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) [wicket-request-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:185) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241) [wicket-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:193) [artifactory-web-application-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:87) [artifactory-web-application-3.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:314)
2015-06-02 16:00:00,006 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.b.GarbageCollectorInfo:78) - Storage garbage collector report:
Number of binaries:      0
Total execution time:    3 millis
Candidates for deletion: 0
Checksums deleted:       0
Binaries deleted:        0
Total size freed:        0 bytes
Current total size:      0 bytes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a full zip, you're all good.
Take a pristine 3.8.0 (or 3.6.0 if you really need to, but why?), [change the storage to MySQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Changing+the+Default+Storage) and then run a full system import.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate the quick response from the author of the application! Could you please check my updated question? At the time of my initial attempt, there was only `3.7.0` around. It would be no problem for me to try it with `3.8.0` although I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Do I need to first upgrade from `2.2.5` to `3.7.0` (keeping Derby) and then migrate to MySQL?

Comment: Right, it seems we had a space-related issue. Are there any properties for setting up the path for backup import extraction location and so on?

Comment: not sure I understand what "properties for setting up the path for backup import extraction location" means